# Is this possible run query SQL select statement on dynamically table name?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.0

I create dynamically table when website is active with this code:

```
public void CreateTable(string tableName, string field1, double field2, ...)
{
  string Raw = string.Format("CREATE TABLE [{0}] ([ID] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL, [{1}] NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL, [{2}] FLOAT NOT NULL, ..., , CONSTRAINT[PK_{0}] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED([ID] ASC);", tableName, field1, field2);
  _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(Raw);
  _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Now I want run query SQL select something like this::

```
private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
public HomeController(ApplicationDbContext context)
{
   _context = context;
}
public void List(string tableName)
{
   string Raw = string.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}];", tableName);
   var table = _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(Raw);
   //--- Do something with table here
}
```

**NOTE:**
I try using reflection like this:

```
var table = _context.GetType().GetProperty(tableName).GetValue(_context) as IQueryable;
```

But not working and return NULL.

*I'm still a newbie on C#, really appreciate if you can show me example based on this code.*

Comment: Have you tried using the adding the schema to the table name.

Comment: What's the output do you want? What's the issue you are facing with this code?

Comment: @KingOfArrows can you explain more?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I want get a list of that table for Searching or Editing and ...

Comment: Hey @XerxesAsimov. So have you tried formatting your select statement like so: `"SELECT * FROM dbo.[{0}]"`. I'm assuming the schema of newly created tables is in dbo.

Comment: @KingOfArrows Yes I tried but returned -1, thanks for comment.

Comment: Hey @XerxesAsimov. Just want to double check that the table actually exists in the database. If it does, you might want to check what kind of permissions this table has for the account the application is using to login to the database with.

Comment: @KingOfArrows Ok I am going double check and I will inform you.

Comment: Hey @KingOfArrows I double check the table actually exists in the database and I check  Permission on container securable that implies granular permission on base securable is ALTER ANY APPLICATION ROLE. Thanks again for comment.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with a Command with to get dynamic objects.

first create a function to get the datarow.

```
 public static IEnumerable<dynamic> CollectionFromSql(this DbContext dbContext, string Sql, Dictionary<string, object> Parameters)
{
    using (var cmd = dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = Sql;
        if (cmd.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            cmd.Connection.Open();

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> param in Parameters)
        {
            DbParameter dbParameter = cmd.CreateParameter();
            dbParameter.ParameterName = param.Key;
            dbParameter.Value = param.Value;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(dbParameter);
        }

        //var retObject = new List<dynamic>();
        using (var dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {

            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                var dataRow = GetDataRow(dataReader);
                yield return dataRow ;

            }
        }


    }
}
```

Then add the data to the dynamic objects.

```
private static dynamic GetDataRow(DbDataReader dataReader)
{
    var dataRow = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, object>;
    for (var fieldCount = 0; fieldCount < dataReader.FieldCount; fieldCount++)
        dataRow.Add(dataReader.GetName(fieldCount), dataReader[fieldCount]);
    return dataRow;
}
```

you can use like this:

```
List<dynamic> MyList = MyDbContext.CollectionFromSql("SELECT * FROM @tableName",
        new Dictionary<string, object> { { "@tableName", tableName } }).ToList();
```

Comment: thanks for answer, currently I am using exactly same way but I am seeking for another way like using ExecuteSqlRaw.